# Inherited values between polygons in QGIS

Tags: polygon, qgis-2, references, calculate-values

In this project, I have three polygons, see the image below

1. `'Polygons_From'`, includes input attributes, i.g. `"Value_1"`, `"Value_2"`, `"Value_3"`, and `$area` for each quadrate (on the image there are two types of them).
2. `'Polygons_To'` polygons for which new values `"Value_1_new"`, `"Value_2_new"`, `"Value_3_new"` need to be defined
3. `'Border'` defines an area where the calculation should be done.

[image: My_input]

My task is to transfer values from `'Polygons_From'` into `'Polygons_To'` based on a certain aspect/ratio. Of course, I can simply achieve it with the `'Union'` function as was suggested in [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214893/calculate-proportional-area-of-polygon-within-another-layers-polygon?rq=1).

It uses `$area`-factor, but perhaps there are better approaches that will lead me to a much more efficient output?

So, I am asking for a recommendation regarding the technique/workflow that can be applied in QGIS 2.18. Shall I consider only `$area` or there are some other criteria?

Moreover, I looking forward to finding some papers that may improve my general understanding of the methodology.

---

**References:**

- [Calculating the area of one layer inside area of another layer QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315029/calculating-the-area-of-one-layer-inside-area-of-another-layer-qgis)
- [Calculating polygon area inside another polygon in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240511/calculating-polygon-area-inside-another-polygon-in-qgis)
- [Combining data from overlapping polygons and assign](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314867/combining-data-from-overlapping-polygons-and-assign)
- [How to combine data from overlapping polygons?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43552/how-to-combine-data-from-overlapping-polygons)
- [Calculating area of polygon inside region?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120462/calculating-area-of-polygon-inside-region?rq=1)
- [Calculate proportional area of polygon within another layer's polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214893/calculate-proportional-area-of-polygon-within-another-layers-polygon?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some `'Polygons_To'` are in more than one `'Polygons_From'` so you should decide to:

- Duplicate polygons in `'Polygons_To'` to match the number of intersections with the `'Polygons_From'` layer. To do this You can use 'Join attributes by location' with one too many options selected.
- Or use the `Union` tool from the 'Vector' menu to split `'Polygons_To'` that intersect with more than one polygon in `'Polygons_From'`.

Think it's also possible to list attributes of all intersecting layers into one column but haven't tried it yet.